# Haxe - Error #1006: insert is not a function

Tags: arrays, flash, insert, haxe

Starting to work with Haxe compiling to a Flash swc file,
it is advised not to use the Array 'insert' in loops or if statements.
I have this code, which requires using loops and if statements

```
if (coa[8] > 0){
    for (ip in 0...s1.length){
    if (s1[ip] == "*"){if (s1[ip-2] <= 0 || s1[ip-2] > 0){if (s1[ip-1] <= 0 || s1[ip-1] > 0){
            var t1 = ip-2;var t2 = (ip-2)*(ip-1);
            s1.insert(t1,t2);s1.splice(ip-2,3);
        coa[8]--;
    }}};
    }  //  loop ip
}
```

The swc file compiles without error but when I plug it into the Flash CC (2014) IDE and test I get the following error

```
Error #1006: insert is not a function.
    at Haxe2D/execute()
```

The arrays are dynamic which could be why the swc compiles without registering an error.

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you didn't call `haxe.initSwc(mc);` before running your code.

It is required as stated at http://old.haxe.org/manual/swc.